# How to get the current month in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqldatetime

I run this type of query every month and I have to change the month number manually for the current-running month.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1
WHERE year = '[current month]'
```

Is there any way I can automate this process through a query which can fit in the month number automatically?

Comment: what DBMS are you on? Please post some example data and expected outcome

Comment: I assume "year" is a typo there, otherwise you've got some very peculiar logic.

Comment: `SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())` or just `MONTH(your_date)` . Just paste your question on google search you will find plenty of ways

Comment: Also, even after you find the current month, is that query really going to work? Your query appears to compare a year to a month?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for find month

```
SELECT MONTH(getdate()) AS "Present Month";
```